# Autofac: How to register multiple types with the same interface for use with a decorator?

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac

I don't see how to register & resolve types with the same interface for use with a decorator. In order to get resolved with the decorator and the same instances of ILogger and IConfiguration, I am declaring them like so:

```
builder.RegisterType<FluentFtpFileHandler>().Named<IFileHandler>("fileHandler");
builder.RegisterType<LocalFileHandler>().Named<IFileHandler>("fileHandler");
builder.RegisterDecorator<IFileHandler>((c, inner) =>
    new LogDecorator(inner.Logger, inner.Configuration, inner), fromKey: "fileHandler");
```

Within a factory class, how can I resolve e. g. an instance of FluentFtpFileHandler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you register multiple types that implement the same interface, last in wins.

```cs
builder.RegisterType<FluentFtpFileHandler>().As<IFileHandler>();
builder.RegisterType<LocalFileHandler>().As<IFileHandler>();
var container = builder.Build();
var handler = container.Resolve<IFileHandler>();
// handler is going to be LocalFileHandler
// because LAST IN WINS.
```

If you need to resolve different handlers in different situations, that's sort of a code smell because you can't actually treat all the handlers the same. [There's an FAQ on that](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html) which explains, with examples, why that's not so great but also provides some ideas for workaround.

Back to the decorator situation, I'd recommend trying out [the new decorator syntax](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html) since it's less confusing than the classic syntax.

```cs
builder.RegisterType<FluentFtpFileHandler>().Named<IFileHandler>("ftpHandler");
builder.RegisterType<LocalFileHandler>().Named<IFileHandler>("localHandler");
builder.RegisterDecorator<LogDecoerator, IFileHandler>();
var container = builder.Build();
var handler = container.ResolveNamed<IFileHandler>("ftpHandler");
// Handler should be a decorated instance of the FTP handler.
```

I'm running this through my "pretty sure this should work" mental compiler, so if the syntax isn't literally copy/paste there, I'm sorry about that.